# Java stream Collection of Maps

Tags: java, dictionary, collections, filter, java-stream

I have a collection:

```
Collection<Map<String, Object>> items = new ArrayList();
Map<String, Object> item1 = new HashMap();
Map<String, Object> item2 = new HashMap();

item1.put("first_name", "john");
item1.put("last_name", "doe");

item2.put("first_name", "jane");
item2.put("last_name", "doe");

items.add(item1);
items.add(item2);
```

I would like to filter out using stream all maps in collection that have "first_name" set as "jane". And it should return a collection of maps (same type).

If it could be done by not using stream I don't mind but I'd prefer stream.

Comment: OK; so you dropped your requirements; but you are not showing any efforts on your side to solve the problem yourself. You see: stackoverflow is not a "we do the coding for you" service

Comment: @Jägermeister You're absolutely right. But I thought that the answer for this question would be so easy in general that it doesn't need my failed attempts. User Mshnik answer below just proved my point.

Comment: Well, you were lucky in this case. Other time of the day, your question might have been closed on you before you were finished saying "gosh, look how many downvotes I got in 15 seconds". The fact that you receive valid answers doesn't turn your question into a good one. And seriously: i think that doing some search on google using the correct terms would have given you good examples in less time than it took you to write up the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not too hard to do. Just add this to your code.

```
Collection<Map<String, Object>> items2 = items.stream().filter(a -> !"jane".equals(a.get("first_name"))).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You do need to specify what happens if the map doesn't contain the key "first_name" at all, I'm assuming that it needs to have a first_name key (that isn't jane) to be valid post-filter.

Additionally, just a heads up. Your existing code isn't using generics correctly; my IDE at least gave me a warning of unchecked casting on your first three lines. After Java 1.7 you can have it infer generic type arguments, but you still need to supply the symbols `<>` to make that happen. Here's a fixed version:

```
Collection<Map<String, Object>> items = new ArrayList<>();
Map<String, Object> item1 = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, Object> item2 = new HashMap<>();
```

Comment: @khelwood fixed, good call. I always try to make sure my maps don't have null keys or values (just remove them when they would be null), but it's a corner case to account for anyways.